# generator for a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, aab

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-itertools

This:

```
import itertools

gen1 = itertools.product('ab', repeat=3)
for i in gen1:
    print(''.join(i), end=' ')
```

prints this:

```
aaa aab aba abb baa bab bba bbb
```

but I also want it to generate `a b aa ab ba bb`. I'm able to do that with this:

```
import itertools

for i in range(1, 4):
    gen2 = itertools.product('ab', repeat=i)
    for j in gen2:
        print(''.join(j), end=' ')
```

which prints this:

```
a b aa ab ba bb aaa aab aba abb baa bab bba bbb
```

Is there a more elegant way of getting this output with a single generator? Something like:

```
import itertools

gen3 = (your code here)
for i in gen3:
    # prints forever in the pattern: a b aa ab ba bb aaa aab aba abb baa bab bba bbb
    print(''.join(i), end=' ')
```

Comment: Is your comment "prints forever" important?

Comment: @tomjn I would say yes, because I'd like to be able to generalize this to any length of 'a's and 'b's. I should make clear that when I said 'prints forever' I meant it continues with aaaa aaab aaba....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would chain multiple iterators together:

```
from itertools import chain, product


gens = chain.from_iterable(product('ab', repeat=i) for i in range(1,4))
for i in gens:
  print(''.join(i), end=' ')
```

If need be, this can be extended to the infinite sequence of values by replacing `range(1,4)` with `itertools.count(1)`.

If your "prints forever" comment means you want to return to `a` after `bbb`, then wrap the chained iterators in `itertools.cycle`.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I wanted. Much more elegant than the other way. Now I can fit everything in a single generator: `gens = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product('ab', repeat=i) for i in itertools.count(1))`